# How to give permission to applications running on GCP cloud run to access gcp services

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I am developing a nodejs application that accesses secrets from gcp secret manager. I ran it locally with directing credentials using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable.

Then I tried deploying this service to google cloud run, now it throws the error

```
 Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied
```

I want to know how to add credentials to cloud-run containers. I saw some implementations where the credential file is included inside the code. what is the best practice of accessing gcp resources from cloud run container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to find [a service account used by your Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity), and grant that service account [a relevant IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control) against the desired secret - most likely a Secret Manager Secret Accessor role
(roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor).

You don’t need any credentials file. And under any circumstances, please, don't keep any credentials in a code repository.

======

Updated following [@kolban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738915/kolban) comment

Comment: I believe this is the documentation link that @al-dann is talking about.  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity